# React state not updating in click event with two functions, but updating with one function

Tags: reactjs, onclick, event-handling, use-state

This one has turned out to be a head scratcher for a while now...

I have a react component that updates state on a click event. The state is a simple boolean so I'm using a ternary operator to toggle state.

This works however as soon as I add a second function to the click event state no longer updates. Any ideas why this is happening and what I'm doing wrong?

**Working code...**

```
  export default function Activity(props) {
   const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false);

   const selectActivity = () => {
     selected ? setSelected(false) : setSelected(true);
     return null;
   };

   const clickHandler = (e) => {
       e.preventDefault();
       selectActivity();
     };

      return (
        <div
          onClick={(e) => clickHandler(e)}
          className={`visit card unassigned ${selected ? 'selected' : null}`}
        >
          //... some content here
        </div>
      );
     }
```

**State not updating...**

```
  export default function Activity(props) {
   const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false);

   const selectActivity = () => {
     selected ? setSelected(false) : setSelected(true);
     return null;
   };

   const clickHandler = (e) => {
       e.preventDefault();
       selectActivity();
       props.collectVisitsForShift(
          props.day,
          props.startTime,
          props.endTime,
          props.customer
       );
     };

      return (
        <div
          onClick={(e) => clickHandler(e)}
          className={`visit card unassigned ${selected ? 'selected' : null}`}
        >
          //... some content here
        </div>
      );
     }
```

Comment: This sound strange, can you try to edit `selectActivity` with `setSelected(prev => !prev)`?

Comment: This code should work just fine as it is, are you sure you are not passing a key to `Activity` which is changing when running `collectVisitsForShift`? If you are, then it will re-mount the component and will reset the state.

Answer (score 1):

I went for a walk and figured this one out. I'm changing state in the parent component from the same onClick event, which means the child component re-renders and gets its default state of 'false'.

I removed the state change from the parent and it works.

Thanks to Andrei for pointing me towards useCallback!

Comment: a re-render ignores initial state, that's the porpuse of an initial state, to set a value on **first** render only. a re-mount will get you the initial state because it is the first render. So the parent is probably re-mount `Activity` due to a changed `key` or conditional rendering.

Answer (score 0):

I loaded your code in a CodeSandbox environment and experienced no problems with the state getting updated. But I don't have access to your `collectVisitsForShift` function, so I couldn't fully reproduce your code.

However, the way you're toggling the state variable doesn't respect the [official guidelines](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html), specifically:

> If the next state depends on the current state, we recommend using the updater function form

Here's what I ended up with in the function body (before returning JSX):

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false);

// - we make use of useCallback so toggleSelected
//   doesn't get re-defined on every re-render.
// - setSelected receives a function that negates the previous value

const toggleSelected = useCallback(() => setSelected(prev => !prev), []);

const clickHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    toggleSelected();
    props.collectVisitsForShift(
        props.day,
        props.startTime,
        props.endTime,
        props.customer
    );
};
```

The documentation for [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback).

Comment: Thanks! That still didn't work... 

My collectVisitsForShift function called from the parent component and sets state there if that helps.

  const collectVisitsForShift = (day, start, end, customer) => {
    const visit = { day, start, end, customer };
    setVisitsForShift((v) => [...v, visit]);
  };

Comment: I see. And does the rendering of `Activity` depend in any way on the contents of the variable that's set by `setVisitsForShift`? Because, as another comment suggested, if it causes `Activity` to to re-mount, it will reset the state.

You can debug this by adding the following hook and checking the console: `useEffect(() => console.log("Activity mounted at ", new Date()), []);`

(It should only log exactly once, when it's first mounted. If it mounts multiple times, the problem is in a parent component).